Using Payara and Netbeans with JDK 21
I am using NB21 and Payara 6.2024.7 . I am debugging and starting Payara from NB . JDk for NB is 21 and Payara states it support manage also JDK 21 but neverthless all these , NB dialog at Server COnfig -> java don't let me to choose JDK 21 ( non present) but I can choice only JDK 11 (it is also present on my machine )
Note that the same NB with Glassfish 7 permit all installed JDK
Why I can't use all installed JDK ? it depend by NB or by Payara ? please, help me !
